# Upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:

Tags: google-app-engine, go, nginx, google-cloud-platform

I'd appreciate some help. I have deployed Go on Google App Engine. The server shuts down for some time which means we cannot get the messages coming in. The trigger is from the upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: The error:

```
2019/10/27 08:25:26 [error] 23#23: *166 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 169.x.x.x, server: _, request: "POST /api/v2/money/topup HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/v2/money/topup", host: “x.x.x”
{
 insertId: "5db55476000502bed07e4583"  
 labels: {
  clone_id: "00c61b117c10abbe48ef11bb1f4ad5987e3ba1611745455daf2a1d6634c62289065e6f871e6c"   
 }
 logName: "projects/showcase/logs/%2Fvar%2Flog%2Fnginx%2Ferror.log"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2019-10-27T08:25:26.334404825Z"  
 resource: {
  labels: {…}   
  type: "gae_app"   
 }
 textPayload: "2019/10/27 08:25:26 [error] 23#23: *166 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 169.254.1.1, server: _, request: "POST /api/v2/money/topup HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/v2/money/topup", host: “x.x.x””  
 timestamp: "2019-10-27T08:25:26.328382Z"  
}
```

The image breakdown is here: [error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffeRP.png)

My Nginx.conf configuration setting:

```
events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {
    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 650;
    keepalive_requests 10000;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    # Logs will appear on the Google Developer's Console when logged to this
    # directory.
    access_log /var/log/app_engine/app.log;
    error_log /var/log/app_engine/app.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    server {
        # Google App Engine expects the runtime to serve HTTP traffic from
        # port 8080.
        listen 8080;
        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

And for the app.yaml is:

```
runtime: go111
instance_class: F2
automatic_scaling:
min_idle_instances: 5
max_idle_instances: automatic  # default value
min_pending_latency: 30ms  # default value
max_pending_latency: automatic
max_concurrent_requests: 50
```

The function that is being called:

```
func (h Handler) UpdateTopUps(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) {

var payload model.C2BCallBack
defer r.Body.Close()
err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&payload)
if err != nil {
    http.Error(w, "Bad Request", http.StatusBadRequest)
    return
}

str := spew.Sdump(payload)
log.Println(str)

id := uuid.NewV4()
if err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Something went wrong: %s", err)
    return
}

if len(payload.MSISDN) > 0 {
    amount := strings.Split(payload.TransAmount, ".")
    balance := strings.Split(payload.OrgAccountBalance, ".")

    var phoneNumber string
    if strings.HasPrefix(payload.MSISDN, "07") {
        phoneNumber = "255" + payload.MSISDN[1:]
    } else {
        phoneNumber = payload.MSISDN
    }

    res := h.database.Create(&model.MpesaTransaction{MpesaTransactionId: id, TransID: payload.TransID, TransTime: payload.TransTime,
        TransAmount: amount[0], BusinessShortCode: payload.BusinessShortCode, OrgAccountBalance: balance[0],
        MSISDN: phoneNumber, FirstName: payload.FirstName, MiddleName: payload.MiddleName, LastName: payload.LastName})

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Internal Server Error", http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    h.updateWalletBalance(res.Value)
}
```

}

It works sometimes and then fails with the above error.

Comment: Da codez, plz! Without the code, it is hard to find out what is going on...

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg I have added the code. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at other similar issues in Stackoverflow I see that this issue is often related to timeouts due to long running operations. Do you still get the same error if you increase the nginx keepalive_timeout parameter?